# how to give mouseover attractive effect to this image reply as soon as possible

Tags: css, html, mouseover, effects

give me code for add mouseover attractive effect to this image as soon as possible. I tried but did not work so anyone have any idea about this then tell me.

Image [image: here]

Comment: Please, for this kind of post, we would like what you have tried or not, so **paste your code** here to see in what we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I did this by using blur effect.

```css
img{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  -webkit-filter: blur(3px);
 filter: blur(3px);
 -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
 transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}
img:hover{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  -webkit-filter: blur(0);
 filter: blur(0);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Z8Z9.png">
</div>
```